# Android: How do I change the height of a ProgressBar?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, layout, progress-bar

I was wondering what is the easiest way to change the height of a ProgressBar in Android?

Thanks,

Tomek

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If your progress bar is defined in the XML layout, it looks like you define its height like so:

```
<ProgressBar  
android:minHeight="20dip" 
android:maxHeight="20dip"/>
```

However I'm just making a guess from [this article](http://bytecrafter.blogspot.com/2008/12/using-horizontal-progress-bar-in.html).

Comment: How about API >11 where its automatically added to actionbar?

Answer (score 22):

You need to replace

```
style=”?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal”
```

to

```
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
```

and layout_height will work

```
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

Comment: How to add attributes like color?!

Comment: You can set the color of the progress and the progress background with "android:progressTint" and "android:progressBackgroundTint" in your SeekBar XML.

Comment: @Luke how do you do that for devices which are pre API 21?

Answer (score 18):

The trick is to have your ProgressBar use the "old", none halo, style. Otherwise it will use a 9-patch image as a progress drawable and you can't change the height unless you manipulate the image. So here is what I did :

the progressbar :

```
<ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/my_progressbar"
  style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="10dp"
  android:progressDrawable="@drawable/horizontal_progress_drawable_red" />
```

the progress drawable (horizontal_progress_drawable_red.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#808080"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#80ff0000"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: what is the root element for the progress drawable supposed to be?
EDIT: <layer-list>

Answer (score 1):

Can use this code :

```
mProgressBar.setScaleY(3f);
```

Or use custom style

values->styles.xml

```
<style name="tallerBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">8dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
</style>
```

Then in your ProgressBar add:

```
style="@style/tallerBarStyle"
```