# Set ProgressBar height

Tags: android, layout, view, height, progress-bar

The question seems stupid but I'm not able to simply define the height of a `ProgressBar`. Neither in code nor the xml file. The `layout_height` property seems act as the margin one, and the original size is much more smaller that I want. I have found almost nothing on the subject so I'm quite confuse. 
The SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739186/android-how-do-i-change-the-height-of-a-progressbar) don't works for me. And I am targeting API 15. 
Is anybody has a solution or an explanation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake. I had paste a sample code like this :

```
<ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/status_progress" 
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"             
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

However the `style` attribute override all others...

To obtain a "basic" horizontal `ProgressBar` you have to set some attributes:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progressDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_horizontal"
    android:indeterminate="false" 
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"/>
```

Of course, some other predefined styles are also available.

Answer (score 0):

For my SeekBar I used

```
android:maxHeight="10dp"
```

Comment: Thanks but as I mentionned, this doesn't work for me (even for a `SeekBar`). `maxHeight` has no effect and `minHeight` seems also impact as `margin`.